# When do autorelease pools drain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I study manual memory management and I wonder when autorelease pools drain.

There is 3 situations, that I found:
1 - in the `main.m`, start from application running and drains on end, therefore releasing all of objects in memory.
2 - when you explicitly create an autorelease pool manually and drain it

Third case is what I'm asking for, and its kind of confusing for me.

As I studied, autorelease objects just like automatic variables in C, that exist only in a logical scope (in function body). Therefore, I suppose that after each function there is a hidden `[pool drain];`

But, it was pointed out to me that it's not correct as I thought. Apple says, that it drains after an "event". That event might occur when user hit button, table view is reloaded for example.

But that information is not enough to see the whole picture. Could you please clarify for me, when exactly a pool drains for objects, like `NSArray *arr = [NSArray array];`?

Comment: The autorelease pool is not drained at the end of every function, but rather every time you yield control back to the run loop.

Comment: @Rob that what I'm asking for, when does that happen?

Comment: @rob okay, thats pretty nice, but how could i determine which method exactly does pool drain? Is there a list of methods? Or some criteria?

Comment: @Rob but there is a lot of methods that call "under the hood", like NSObject +load. Obviously, pool doesn't drain anytime NSObject load. I like your explanation but still can't see whole picture :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79064/discussion-between-rob-and-evgeniy-kleban).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is not specific on when the "main" autorelease pool drains, but generally you can assume it is drained at the end of the application's main event loop.

Here's what happens with regards to autorelease pools:

1. An autorelease pool is created when an application starts.
2. When another pool is created, it is added to the top of the autorelease pool stack.
3. When a `autorelease` is sent to an object, it is added to the autorelease pool at the top of the stack.
4. When `release` is sent to an autorelease pool, it, in turn, sends `release` to any object in the pool.

#4 typically happens automatically (for the main autorelease pool) at the end of the main event loop.

The documentation for [`NSAutoreleasePool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/) has more information, including this relevant tidbit:

> The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event.

Comment: I'm sorry but it still far from clear for me. if i understand correct, main event loop is the main thread, that  start when application launch and end when it finish running. I understand that autorelease pool in main is drain when application end. But what about objects that have to be released during lifetime of an application? Obviously. app can't "hold" all objects in memory until it ends, therefore, it have to figure out when it need to drain other pools, otherwise an app would run out of memory. I wonder how and when it drain those pools.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: The main event loop keeps looping for the lifetime of the application (as it has to process UI events), so the main autorelease pool will be drained many times over the lifetime of an application.

Comment: I thought there is couple of pools and each have some objects in it, and it drain in some occasion. But if there are only 1 pool and it drains many times, all auto released objects got destroyed many times during lifetime? Is that correct? (Only those with retain count > 1 survive)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: When a pool drains, it removes the object is is tracking and sends it a `release` message. (Well, it's a bit more complicated -- an object can be added to an autorelease pool more than once -- but conceptually you can think of it as working that way.) So an object will only receive one `release` message for each `autorelease` message it receives.

Comment: does that mean, it destroy autorelease pool and create it again and again on the same thread?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: According to the `NSAutoreleasePool` documentation, yes.

Comment: @mipadi I am still not clear about words "looping for the lifetime of the application". When loop ends iteration at some point ( processing of current event is finished ), then autorelease pool at the top of the stack of thread's autorelease pools will be drained? ( According to documentation, each thread has a stack of autorelease pools )

Comment: @gaussblurinc: Yes. The event loop continues for the lifetime of the application, and the autorelease pool at the top of the stack (which generally should be the only one by the time the end of the main event loop is reached) will be drained.

Answer (score 4):

When I'm using reverse engineering tool to analysis Foundation framework. Then I found autorelease pool created at begin of runloop and release at end of runloop.
image: [image: autorelease start at runloop]